# How to Post Activity Stories Grouped under the App in Newsfeed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I see stories on the newsfeed where the app is listed above the user posts. As if posts are grouped by application. Here is a screenshot. I want to be able to recreate this.

[feed post http://174.37.0.250/~thepoker/images/post.jpg](http://174.37.0.250/~thepoker/images/post.jpg)

If anyone can tell me how to post this from my app it would be appreciated. I basically need to be able to generate this newsfeed unit.

Answer (score 0):

Those aggregations are handled by Facebook. There is nothing your app can do via the API to "force" Facebook to group them.